# Symfony 2 Disabled Option

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Ok, I was having / am having an issue with Twig trying to add in disabled option on a 'pull-down' select list. I have a To & From, for all the days in the week.

However I have build a work around, I feed the data into the Type and set up a little function to see if the form element is disabled or not and set it according.

So where is what I have in my controller

```
 $SetData = $this->getDoctrine()
                   ->getRepository('Bundle:XXXXXInfo')
                   ->findOneById($ID);

 $Form = $this->createForm(new InfoType($SetData), $SetData, ['action' => $this->generateUrl('formPath')])
                    ->add('save', 'submit', ['label' => $ButtonLabel,
                                             'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'],
                                            ]);
```

This is how my InfoType Form looks,

```
 public function __construct($Data) {
    $this->MyInfo = $Data; 
}

private function SetDisabledOption($From, $To) {

    if ($From === NULL && $To === NULL ) {
        $DisabledOption = true;
    } else {
        $DisabledOption = false;
    }

    return $DisabledOption; 
}
```

And then in the 'buildForm' function of that Type,

```
 $CurrentData = $this->MyInfo;

 $Monday = $this->SetDisabledOption($CurrentData->getMonFrom(), $CurrentData->getMonTo());
```

This is the only work around I have found as I tried all sorts of code for the 'attr' and with without on the form widget I wanted to to disable. I could not get that working. Then, looking over what I wanted it to do, I thought it would result in cleaner code if I retained all my logic (if statements) to the Controller / Form Builder.

However when these options are now set to NULL and the disabled option is true, removing it with a little bit of Jquery and a checkbox, it does not remove it and the values are still set as null?

Now I have tried using  `getData()`  on my Form, still null - However when I check all the PHP  `$_POST`  data, values are available when the disabled has been removed from it.

So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html - this will allow you to dynamically modify whether a field is disabled based on a field that you pass to the form.

Comment: Thanks for the link mate! I did not think anyone would post on this question! - However I got a work around in place, which I think is a better method. I add a 'readonly' tag rather than the disabled, which seems to work in the way I want. When I get a second I see if I can post my work around.

Comment: Yeah, if you set it to disabled then Symfony will completely ignore any value passed in, where readonly should just affect the HTML.